# How can i show gratitude for exceptional help?

Tags: discussion, bounty, contributing

Yes, I read this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

The thing is, I asked a question, to show me directions how to approach a problem Io find difficult, and to help me judge whether or not I am able to solve it. But a user went ahead and started doing all of the hard work in my place. I mean a lot of hard work. I feel he deserves more than a vote up and accept. Since I am not adept at LaTex, there are no questions I can realy answer right now, so "pay it forward" is frankly not possible now. Is there something else I can do for him or the community?

Question mentioned: [Is there a tool to make a complicated Table like this one?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164925/is-there-a-tool-to-make-a-complicated-table-like-this-one)

User: [Niel de Beaudrap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/911/niel-de-beaudrap)

Comment: Related: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2971/bounty-as-thank-you

Comment: @T.Verron If my question don't qualify as duplicate, please make your comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Going through all this trouble to ask this question is more than enough. Just put also the question and the user name and we'll suffocate him with wet kisses (her with firm handshakes.... Man political correctness sucks big time :P )

Comment: Really appreciate your good attitude, just visit tex.sx often and observe/read/upvote Q & A for a while and you can give back soon in terms of `Bounty` and your `participation effort`. Related Thread on How one can contribute [When should I start to give back?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3841/15717)

Comment: Oh no, you meant the _other_ answer:-)  The site mechanisms allow you do donate a "bounty" in such circumstances. Ie give away some of your reputation points. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/bounty  for how bounties work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry David, the other answer is just outstanding. But you did a great job as well!